# getResourceAsStream returning null with android when trying to retrieve JSON file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Trying to assign `in` to the file `credentials.json` in Android Studio but when I try to print `in` to check the that the value isn't `null` it returns `null`

```
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/raw/credentials.json");
```

the project structure is:

```
app
   |-src
      |main
          |java
               |com.appProject
                              |myClass
          |res
              |raw
                  |credentials.json
```

The file is called from a class outside of the main activity called `myClass`.

Either the method I need a different approach to getting a stream from a json file or my file path is all wrong

**EDIT**

*The answer given is correct, but it is vital that `context` is set correctly in your application as well, as I made the mistake of not setting it up correctly to the MainActivity*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you access a raw resource in Android.

To get an `InputStream` on a raw resource, you can use a `Context`, such as your `Activity`:

```
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);
```

Comment: Tried to use `InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);`  but I got the error `Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `context`  I'm calling the code from the `myClass` class which isn't the `MainActivity` so how do I properly declare it?

Comment: @T.kat: Your code is in a method on `myClass`. That method should take a `Context` as a parameter. When you call that method from your `Activity`, pass `this` as the `Context`.

Comment: `context` now has a value but i am still getting a `null pointer exception` on the raw file I am trying to get